# Sitemesh3 Decorator only works with JSP extension

Tags: jsp, struts2, decorator, sitemesh

I'm using Sitemesh3 and I can only get it to decorate views WITH a JSP extension.  Normal extensionless actions don't get decorated.

For example:

http://localhost:8080/index  [No decoration]

http://locathost:8080/index.jsp  [Gets decorated]

~~

What am I missing?

=======

**sitemesh3.xml**

```
<sitemesh>
    <mapping>
        <path>/*</path>
        <decorator>/WEB-INF/decorators/master.jsp</decorator>
    </mapping>
</sitemesh>
```

======

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

=====

**struts.xml**

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="index">
            <result>/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

======

**File Structure**

```
webapp
|- WEB-INF
|- |- master.jsp
|- |- sitemesh3.xml
|- index.jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

The Sitemesh `filter-mapping` needed to be changed like so:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```